# Set Negative Values on Currency Field while loading data with dataloader

Tags: data-loader, currency

I am trying to upload the data using workbench. 
 
The file contains columns as Id, currencyField.

Here is the sample: 
ID  Column1    | CurrencyField Column 2 
XXXXXXX  | 1234.33 
YYYYYYY  | -5678.99

 
After I load(update) the data into salesforce, I am seeing the currency field as below :  
Record1 -> CurrencyField__c = 1234.33 
**Record2 -> CurrencyField__c = (5678.99)**  
FYI.. I also changed the formate of that CurrencyField column as below :
[image]

Please help on how can I load negative currency values and stores in salesforce without "()".
I mean, **Record2 -> CurrencyField__c = -5678.99**  
I appreciate your help :)

Comment: This is a standard US currency formatting for negative amounts. It's stored as `-5678.99` in the database

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy, Yes it stores as -5678.99 in database. But I want to show -5678.99 on Record datail page as well as in reports. So that it will appear to be user friendly.

Comment: The easiest would be to convert a `Field type` to `Number`